# How to use COPY command in Docker build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to perform some automation to while build my docker image. Below is my code run in Windows 8, Kitematic, Virtual Box:

```
FROM node:6

# Create directory
RUN mkdir -p /tempDir && mkdir -p /tempDir/built && mkdir -p /data

# Setup build environment
COPY . /tempDir
RUN npm install -g gulp typings 

# Build from source
WORKDIR /tempDir 
RUN npm install && typings install && gulp build
```

Up to here, everything is fine, success to build my typescript to javascript in /tempDir/built directory. I bash into my container, it look like this:

```
tempDir/gulpfile.js
tempDir/typings
tempDir/src 
tempDir/built
```

My next step is to move this built folder to another directory then delete tempDir. My problem is that COPY command not work as I expected.

```
COPY built/* /data/
```

I keep on getting error like 'no such file or directory' or 'lstat built/: no such file or directory'. 
I tried ./built, ./built/, built/, /tempDir/built/, and other still getting the same error. 
Anyone can help on this?

Comment: At the top of your Dockerfile, you don't have to repeat `mkdir` every time.  A single command would suffice: `RUN mkdir -p /tmpDir/built /data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to copy something that's in your container and so `COPY` will not work because it is specific to your Host --> Container.

Instead you will have to run a bash command inside your container.

`RUN cp -rf built /data/`

Answer (score 6):

`COPY` copies files from your host filesystem into the container.  It looks like you want to copy files from one directory in the container to another.  For that you need to use `RUN` and `cp`

```
RUN cp -r built/* /data/
```

Since you will be removing the `/tempDir/` directory, you can speed things up a bit by renaming the directory:

```
RUN mv built /data
```

This way you don't have to copy data around and then delete the originals.

Comment: Thank you to enlighten usage of COPY, but I still getting "The command '/bin/sh -c cp built/* /data/' returned a non-zero code: 1" error, any idea what it mean?

Comment: Probably because you have sub-directories in `/built` which I neglected to account for.  As Mike Tung points out below, try `RUN cp -r built/* /data/.`

Comment: you don't actually need the `*` it automatically gets handled by the `rf`

Comment: @MikeTung I like the `*` and the `.` because it makes the action explicit.  Following this convention all of the time, you don't have to remember subtle differences in behavior between `cp`, `mv`, and `rsync`.