# Docker ADD (download) folder and files to image (using centos)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Using the ADD command in a Dockerfile, I am trying to download the entire content of a folder to an image.

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y install httpd

ADD https://github.com/ricardoandre97/docker-en-resources/tree/master/docker-images/templates/startbootstrap-freelancer-master/ /temp/
RUN cp /temp/startbootstrap-freelancer-master/ /var/www/html/

CMD apachectl -DFOREGROUND
```

Now, the folder /temp contains a file (not a folder!) named `startbootstrap-freelancer-master`.

As described in here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66187161/download-a-folder-from-github-with-docker-add[][1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66187161/download-a-folder-from-github-with-docker-add%5B%5D%5B1%5D), I cannot use the alpine command, since I am in centos:

```
RUN svn export https://github.com/...
```

I tried with curl:

```
RUN curl -L https://github.com/ricardoandre97/docker-en-resources/tree/master/docker-images/templates/startbootstrap-freelancer-master/
```

but I don't find where it downloaded.

Comment: It should be in `/temp/` inside the isolated image filesystem.  You might be running into trouble with the following line, which tries to `COPY` from `./temp/` on the host system and isn't finding it.  `RUN cp ...` (or `RUN mv ...`) might be what you're looking for in that case.  [How to use COPY command in Docker build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481276/how-to-use-copy-command-in-docker-build) describes this specific problem.

Comment: Totally true. Even if the ADD command worked, the COPY command isn't what I intended to do. In this case it would be improper. I am going to edit the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a specific dir from github with `ADD`. It is like `wget`ing the address and copying it to the image. It is not working that way. There is a long discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo).

A solution would be to `git clone` all the repo, keep what you want, and remove unwanted parts.